# WASM (WebAssembly) project stops running unexpectedly in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2019, webassembly

All other projects are running fine in my solution.

However, my WebAssembly (WASM) project is not running and throwing exceptions with no details.

Just one dynamic file opened with the name:

```
localhost:44337/_framework/dotnet.5.0.14.js [dynamic]
```

This file disappeared when I stopped the project.

This is the code:

```
var Module=typeof Module!=="undefined"?Module:{};var moduleOverrides={};var key;for(key in Module){if(Module.hasOwnProperty(key)){moduleOverrides[key]=Module[key]}}var arguments_=[];var thisProgram="./this.program";var quit_=function(status,toThrow){throw toThrow};var ENVIRONMENT_IS_WEB=false;var ENVIRONMENT_IS_WORKER=false;var ENVIRONMENT_IS_NODE=false;var ENVIRONMENT_IS_SHELL=false;ENVIRONMENT_IS_WEB=typeof window==="object";ENVIRONMENT_IS_WORKER=typeof importScripts==="function";ENVIRONMENT_IS_NODE=typeof process==="object"&&typeof process.versions==="object"&&typeof process.versions.node==="string";ENVIRONMENT_IS_SHELL=!ENVIRONMENT_IS_WEB&&!ENVIRONMENT_IS_NODE&&!ENVIRONMENT_IS_WORKER;var scriptDirectory="";function locateFile(path){if(Module["locateFile"]){return Module["locateFile"](path,scriptDirectory)}return scriptDirectory+path}var read_,readAsync,readBinary,setWindowTitle;var nodeFS;var nodePath;if(ENVIRONMENT_IS_NODE){if(ENVIRONMENT_IS_WORKER){scriptDirectory=require("path").dirname(scriptDirectory)+"/"}else{scriptDirectory=__dirname+"/"}read_=function shell_read(filename,binary){if(!nodeFS)nodeFS=require("fs");if(!nodePath)nodePath=require("path");filename=nodePath["normalize"](filename);return nodeFS["readFileSync"](filename,binary?null:"utf8")};readBinary=function readBinary(filename){var ret=read_(filename,true);if(!ret.buffer){ret=new Uint8Array(ret)}assert(ret.buffer);return ret};if(process["argv"].length>1){thisProgram=process["argv"][1].replace(/\\/g,"/")}arguments_=process["argv"].slice(2);if(typeof module!=="undefined"){module["exports"]=Module}process["on"]("uncaughtException",function(ex){if(!(ex instanceof ExitStatus)){throw ex}});process["on"]("unhandledRejection",abort);quit_=function(status){process["exit"](status)};Module["inspect"]=function(){return"[Emscripten Module object]"}}else if(ENVIRONMENT_IS_SHELL){if(typeof read!="undefined"){read_=function shell_read(f){return read(f)}}readBinary=function readBinary(f){var data;if(typeof readbuffer==="function"){return new Uint8Array(readbuffer(f))}data=read(f,"binary");assert(typeof data==="object");return data};if(typeof scriptArgs!="undefined"){arguments_=scriptArgs}else if(typeof arguments!="undefined"){arguments_=arguments}if(typeof quit==="function"){quit_=function(status){quit(status)}}if(typeof print!=="undefined"){if(typeof console==="undefined")console={};console.log=print;console.warn=console.error=typeof printErr!=="undefined"?printErr:print}}else if(ENVIRONMENT_IS_WEB||ENVIRONMENT_IS_WORKER){if(ENVIRONMENT_IS_WORKER){scriptDirectory=self.location.href}else if(document.currentScript){scriptDirectory=document.currentScript.src}if(scriptDirectory.indexOf("blob:")!==0){scriptDirectory=scriptDirectory.substr(0,scriptDirectory.lastIndexOf("/")+1)}else{scriptDirectory=""}{read_=function shell_read(url){var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest;xhr.open("GET",url,false);xhr.send(null);return xhr.responseText};if(ENVIRONMENT_IS_WORKER){readBinary=function readBinary(url){var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest;xhr.open("GET",url,false);xhr.responseType="arraybuffer";xhr.send(null);return new Uint8Array(xhr.response)}}readAsync=function readAsync(url,onload,onerror){var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest;xhr.open("GET",url,true);xhr.responseType="arraybuffer";xhr.onload=function xhr_onload(){if(xhr.status==200||xhr.status==0&&xhr.response){onload(xhr.response);return}onerror()};xhr.onerror=onerror;xhr.send(null)}}setWindowTitle=function(title){document.title=title}}else{}var out=Module["print"]||console.log.bind(console);var err=Module["printErr"]||console.warn.bind(console);for(key in moduleOverrides){if(moduleOverrides.hasOwnProperty(key)){Module[key]=moduleOverrides[key]}}moduleOverrides=null;if(Module["arguments"])arguments_=Module["arguments"];if(Module["thisProgram"])thisProgram=Module["thisProgram"];if(Module["quit"])quit_=Module["quit"];var STACK_ALIGN=16;function dynamicAlloc(size){var ret=HEAP32[DYNAMICTOP_PTR>>2];var end=ret+size+15&-16;HEAP32[DYNAMICTOP_PTR>>2]=end;return ret}function alignMemory(size,factor){if(!factor)factor=STACK_ALIGN;return Math.ceil(size/factor)*factor}function convertJsFunctionToWasm(func,sig){if(typeof WebAssembly.Function==="function"){var typeNames={"i":"i32","j":"i64","f":"f32","d":"f64"};var type={parameters:[],results:sig[0]=="v"?[]:[typeNames[sig[0]]]};for(var i=1;i<sig.length;++i){type.parameters.push(typeNames[sig[i]])}return new WebAssembly.Function(type,func)}var typeSection=[1,0,1,96];var sigRet=sig.slice(0,1);var sigParam=sig.slice(1);var typeCodes={"i":127,"j":126,"f":125,"d":124};typeSection.push(sigParam.length);for(var i=0;i<sigParam.length;++i){typeSection.push(typeCodes[sigParam[i]])}if(sigRet=="v"){typeSection.push(0)}else{typeSection=typeSection.concat([1,typeCodes[sigRet]])}typeSection[1]=typeSection.length-2;var bytes=new Uint8Array([0,97,115,109,1,0,0,0].concat(typeSection,[2,7,1,1,101,1,102,0,0,7,5,1,1,102,0,0]));var module=new WebAssembly.Module(bytes);var instance=new WebAssembly.Instance(module,{"e":{"f":func}});var wrappedFunc=instance.exports["f"];return wrappedFunc}var freeTableIndexes=[];var functionsInTableMap;function addFunctionWasm(func,sig){var table=wasmTable;if(!functionsInTableMap){functionsInTableMap=new WeakMap;for(var i=0;i<table.length;i++){var item=table.get(i);if(item){functionsInTableMap.set(item,i)}}}if(functionsInTableMap.has(func)){return functionsInTableMap.get(func)}var ret;if(freeTableIndexes.length){ret=freeTableIndexes.pop()}else{ret=table.length;try{table.grow(1)}catch(err){if(!(err instanceof RangeError)){throw err}throw"Unable to grow wasm table. Set ALLOW_TABLE_GROWTH."}}try{table.set(ret,func)}catch(err){if(!(err instanceof TypeError)){throw err}var wrapped=convertJsFunctionToWasm(func,sig);table.set(ret,wrapped)}functionsInTableMap.set(func,ret);return ret}function addFunction(func,sig){return addFunctionWasm(func,sig)}var tempRet0=0;var setTempRet0=function(value){tempRet0=value};var getTempRet0=function(){return tempRet0};var wasmBinary;if(Module["wasmBinary"])wasmBinary=Module["wasmBinary"];var noExitRuntime;if(Module["noExitRuntime"])noExitRuntime=Module["noExitRuntime"];if(typeof WebAssembly!=="object"){abort("no native wasm support detected")}function setValue(ptr,value,type,noSafe){type=type||"i8";if(type.charAt(type.length-1)==="*")type="i32";switch(type){case"i1":HEAP8[ptr>>0]=value;break;case"i8":HEAP8[ptr>>0]=value;break;case"i16":HEAP16[ptr>>1]=value;break;case"i32":HEAP32[ptr>>2]=value;break;case"i64":tempI64=[value>>>0,(tempDouble=value,+Math_abs(tempDouble)>=1?tempDouble>0?(Math_min(+Math_floor(tempDouble/4294967296),4294967295)|0)>>>0:~~+Math_ceil((tempDouble-+(~~tempDouble>>>0))/4294967296)>>>0:0)],HEAP32[ptr>>2]=tempI64[0],HEAP32[ptr+4>>2]=tempI64[1];break;case"float":HEAPF32[ptr>>2]=value;break;case"double":HEAPF64[ptr>>3]=value;break;default:abort("invalid type for setValue: "+type)}}function getValue(ptr,type,noSafe){type=type||"i8";if(type.charAt(type.length-1)==="*")type="i32";switch(type){case"i1":return HEAP8[ptr>>0];case"i8":return HEAP8[ptr>>0];case"i16":return HEAP16[ptr>>1];case"i32":return HEAP32[ptr>>2];case"i64":return HEAP32[ptr>>2];case"float":return HEAPF32[ptr>>2];case"double":return HEAPF64[ptr>>3];default:abort("invalid type for getValue: "+type)}return null}var wasmMemory;var wasmTable=new WebAssembly.Table({"initial":3950,"maximum":3950,"element":"anyfunc"});var ABORT=false;var EXITSTATUS=0;function assert(condition,text){if(!condition){abort("Assertion failed: "+text)}}function getCFunc(ident){var func=Module["_"+ident];assert(func,"Cannot call unknown function "+ident+", make sure it is exported");return func}function ccall(ident,returnType,argTypes,args,opts){var toC={"string":function(str){var ret=0;if(str!==null&&str!==undefined&&str!==0){var len=(str.length<<2)+1;ret=stackAlloc(len);stringToUTF8(str,ret,len)}return ret},"array":function(arr){var ret=stackAlloc(arr.length);writeArrayToMemory(arr,ret);return ret}};function convertReturnValue(ret){if(returnType==="string")return UTF8ToString(ret);if(returnType==="boolean")return Boolean(ret);return ret}var func=getCFunc(ident);var cArgs=[];var stack=0;if(args){for(var i=0;i<args.length;i++){var converter=toC[argTypes[i]];if(converter){if(stack===0)stack=stackSave();cArgs[i]=converter(args[i])}else{cArgs[i]=args[i]}}}var ret=func.apply(null,cArgs);ret=convertReturnValue(ret);if(stack!==0)stackRestore(stack);return ret}function cwrap(ident,returnType,argTypes,opts){argTypes=argTypes||[];var numericArgs=argTypes.every(function(type){return type==="number"});var numericRet=returnType!=="string";if(numericRet&&numericArgs&&!opts){return getCFunc(ident)}return function(){return ccall(ident,returnType,argTypes,arguments,opts)}}function getMemory(size){if(!runtimeInitialized)return dynamicAlloc(size);return _malloc(size)}var UTF8Decoder=typeof TextDecoder!=="undefined"?new TextDecoder("utf8"):undefined;function UTF8ArrayToString(heap,idx,maxBytesToRead){var endIdx=idx+maxBytesToRead;var endPtr=idx;while(heap[endPtr]&&!(endPtr>=endIdx))++endPtr;if(endPtr-idx>16&&heap.subarray&&UTF8Decoder){return UTF8Decoder.decode(heap.subarray(idx,endPtr))}else{var str="";while(idx<endPtr){var u0=heap[idx++];if(!(u0&128)){str+=String.fromCharCode(u0);continue}var u1=heap[idx++]&63;if((u0&224)==192){str+=String.fromCharCode((u0&31)<<6|u1);continue}var u2=heap[idx++]&63;if((u0&240)==224){u0=(u0&15)<<12|u1<<6|u2}else{u0=(u0&7)<<18|u1<<12|u2<<6|heap[idx++]&63}if(u0<65536){str+=String.fromCharCode(u0)}else{var ch=u0-65536;str+=String.fromCharCode(55296|ch>>10,56320|ch&1023)}}}return str}function UTF8ToString(ptr,maxBytesToRead){return ptr?UTF8ArrayToString(HEAPU8,ptr,maxBytesToRead):""}function stringToUTF8Array(str,heap,outIdx,maxBytesToWrite){if(!(maxBytesToWrite>0))return 0;var startIdx=outIdx;var endIdx=outIdx+maxBytesToWrite-1;for(var i=0;i<str.length;++i){var u=str.charCodeAt(i);if(u>=55296&&u<=57343){var u1=str.charCodeAt(++i);u=65536+((u&1023)<<10)|u1&1023}if(u<=127){if(outIdx>=endIdx)break;heap[outIdx++]=u}else if(u<=2047){if(outIdx+1>=endIdx)break;heap[outIdx++]=192|u>>6;heap[outIdx++]=128|u&63}else if(u<=65535){if(outIdx+2>=endIdx)break;heap[outIdx++]=224|u>>12;heap[outIdx++]=128|u>>6&63;heap[outIdx++]=128|u&63}else{if(outIdx+3>=endIdx)break;heap[outIdx++]=240|u>>18;heap[outIdx++]=128|u>>12&63;heap[outIdx++]=128|u>>6&63;heap[outIdx++]=128|u&63}}heap[outIdx]=0;return outIdx-startIdx}function stringToUTF8(str,outPtr,maxBytesToWrite){return stringToUTF8Array(str,HEAPU8,outPtr,maxBytesToWrite)}function lengthBytesUTF8(str){var len=0;for(var i=0;i<str.length;++i){var u=str.charCodeAt(i);if(u>=55296&&u<=57343)u=65536+((u&1023)<<10)|str.charCodeAt(++i)&1023;if(u<=127)++len;else if(u<=2047)len+=2;else if(u<=65535)len+=3;else len+=4}return len}function stringToUTF16(str,outPtr,maxBytesToWrite){if(maxBytesToWrite===undefined){maxBytesToWrite=2147483647}if(maxBytesToWrite<2)return 0;maxBytesToWrite-=2;var startPtr=outPtr;var numCharsToWrite=maxBytesToWrite<str.length*2?maxBytesToWrite/2:str.length;for(var i=0;i<numCharsToWrite;++i){var codeUnit=str.charCodeAt(i);HEAP16[outPtr>>1]=codeUnit;outPtr+=2}HEAP16[outPtr>>1]=0;return outPtr-startPtr}function allocateUTF8(str){var size=lengthBytesUTF8(str)+1;var ret=_malloc(size);if(ret)stringToUTF8Array(str,HEAP8,ret,size);return ret}function writeArrayToMemory(array,buffer){HEAP8.set(array,buffer)}function writeAsciiToMemory(str,buffer,dontAddNull){for(var i=0;i<str.length;++i){HEAP8[buffer++>>0]=str.charCodeAt(i)}if(!dontAddNull)HEAP8[buffer>>0]=0}var WASM_PAGE_SIZE=65536;function alignUp(x,multiple){if(x%multiple>0){x+=multiple-x%multiple}return x}var buffer,HEAP8,HEAPU8,HEAP16,HEAPU16,HEAP32,HEAPU32,HEAPF32,HEAPF64;function updateGlobalBufferAndViews(buf){buffer=buf;Module["HEAP8"]=HEAP8=new Int8Array(buf);Module["HEAP16"]=HEAP16=new Int16Array(buf);Module["HEAP32"]=HEAP32=new Int32Array(buf);Module["HEAPU8"]=HEAPU8=new Uint8Array(buf);Module["HEAPU16"]=HEAPU16=new Uint16Array(buf);Module["HEAPU32"]=HEAPU32=new Uint32Array(buf);Module["HEAPF32"]=HEAPF32=new Float32Array(buf);Module["HEAPF64"]=HEAPF64=new Float64Array(buf)}var STACK_MAX=614352,DYNAMIC_BASE=5857232,DYNAMICTOP_PTR=614192;var TOTAL_STACK=5242880;var INITIAL_INITIAL_MEMORY=Module["INITIAL_MEMORY"]||16777216;if(Module["wasmMemory"]){wasmMemory=Module["wasmMemory"]}else{wasmMemory=new WebAssembly.Memory({"initial":INITIAL_INITIAL_MEMORY/WASM_PAGE_SIZE,"maximum":2147483648/WASM_PAGE_SIZE})}if(wasmMemory){buffer=wasmMemory.buffer}INITIAL_INITIAL_MEMORY=buffer.byteLength;updateGlobalBufferAndViews(buffer);HEAP32[DYNAMICTOP_PTR>>2]=DYNAMIC_BASE;function callRuntimeCallbacks(callbacks){while(callbacks.length>0){var callback=callbacks.shift();if(typeof callback=="function"){callback(Module);continue}var func=callback.func;if(typeof func==="number"){if(callback.arg===undefined){Module["dynCall_v"](func)}else{Module["dynCall_vi"](func,callback.arg)}}else{func(callback.arg===undefined?null:callback.arg)}}}var __ATPRERUN__=[];var __ATINIT__=[];var __ATMAIN__=[];var __ATEXIT__=[];var __ATPOSTRUN__=[];var runtimeInitialized=false;var runtimeExited=false;function preRun(){if(Module["preRun"]){if(typeof Module["preRun"]=="function")Module["preRun"]=[Module["preRun"]];while(Module["preRun"].length){addOnPreRun(Module["preRun"].shift())}}callRuntimeCallbacks(__ATPRERUN__)}function initRuntime(){runtimeInitialized=true;if(!Module["noFSInit"]&&!FS.init.initialized)FS.init();TTY.init();SOCKFS.root=FS.mount(SOCKFS,{},null);callRuntimeCallbacks(__ATINIT__)}function preMain(){FS.ignorePermissions=false;callRuntimeCallbacks(__ATMAIN__)}function exitRuntime(){runtimeExited=true}function postRun(){if(Module["postRun"]){if(typeof Module["postRun"]=="function")Module["postRun"]=[Module["postRun"]];while(Module["postRun"].length){addOnPostRun(Module["postRun"].shift())}}callRuntimeCallbacks(__ATPOSTRUN__)}function addOnPreRun(cb){__ATPRERUN__.unshift(cb)}function addOnPostRun(cb){__ATPOSTRUN__.unshift(cb)}var Math_abs=Math.abs;var Math_ceil=Math.ceil;var Math_floor=Math.floor;var Math_min=Math.min;var runDependencies=0;var runDependencyWatcher=null;var dependenciesFulfilled=null;function getUniqueRunDependency(id){return id}function addRunDependency(id){runDependencies++;if(Module["monitorRunDependencies"]){Module["monitorRunDependencies"](runDependencies)}}function removeRunDependency(id){runDependencies--;if(Module["monitorRunDependencies"]){Module["monitorRunDependencies"](runDependencies)}if(runDependencies==0){if(runDependencyWatcher!==null){clearInterval(runDependencyWatcher);runDependencyWatcher=null}if(dependenciesFulfilled){var callback=dependenciesFulfilled;dependenciesFulfilled=null;callback()}}}Module["preloadedImages"]={};Module["preloadedAudios"]={};function abort(what){if(Module["onAbort"]){Module["onAbort"](what)}what+="";err(what);ABORT=true;EXITSTATUS=1;what="abort("+what+"). Build with -s ASSERTIONS=1 for more info.";var e=new WebAssembly.RuntimeError(what);throw e}function hasPrefix(str,prefix){return String.prototype.startsWith?str.startsWith(prefix):str.indexOf(prefix)===0}var dataURIPrefix="data:application/octet-stream;base64,";function isDataURI(filename){return hasPrefix(filename,dataURIPrefix)}var fileURIPrefix="file://";function isFileURI(filename){return hasPrefix(filename,fileURIPrefix)}var wasmBinaryFile="dotnet.wasm";if(!isDataURI(wasmBinaryFile)){wasmBinaryFile=locateFile(wasmBinaryFile)}function getBinary(){try{if(wasmBinary){return new Uint8Array(wasmBinary)}if(readBinary){return readBinary(wasmBinaryFile)}else{throw"both async and sync fetching of the wasm failed"}}catch(err){abort(err)}}function getBinaryPromise(){if(!wasmBinary&&(ENVIRONMENT_IS_WEB||ENVIRONMENT_IS_WORKER)&&typeof fetch==="function"&&!isFileURI(wasmBinaryFile)){return fetch(wasmBinaryFile,{credentials:"same-origin"}).then(function(response){if(!response["ok"]){throw"failed to load wasm binary file at '"+wasmBinaryFile+"'"}return response["arrayBuffer"]()}).catch(function(){return getBinary()})}return Promise.resolve().then(getBinary)}function createWasm(){var info={"a":asmLibraryArg};function receiveInstance(instance,module){var exports=instance.exports;Module["asm"]=exports;removeRunDependency("wasm-instantiate")}addRunDependency("wasm-instantiate");function receiveInstantiatedSource(output){receiveInstance(output["instance"])}function instantiateArrayBuffer(receiver){return getBinaryPromise().then(function(binary){return WebAssembly.instantiate(binary,info)}).then(receiver,function(reason){err("failed to asynchronously prepare wasm: "+reason);abort(reason)})}function instantiateAsync(){if(!wasmBinary&&typeof WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming==="function"&&!isDataURI(wasmBinaryFile)&&!isFileURI(wasmBinaryFile)&&typeof fetch==="function"){fetch(wasmBinaryFile,{credentials:"same-origin"}).then(function(response){var result=WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming(response,info);return result.then(receiveInstantiatedSource,function(reason){err("wasm streaming compile failed: "+reason);err("falling back to ArrayBuffer instantiation");return instantiateArrayBuffer(receiveInstantiatedSource)})})}else{return instantiateArrayBuffer(receiveInstantiatedSource)}}if(Module["instantiateWasm"]){try{var exports=Module["instantiateWasm"](info,receiveInstance);return exports}catch(e){err("Module.instantiateWasm callback failed with error: "+e);return false}}instantiateAsync();return{}}var tempDouble;var tempI64;var ASM_CONSTS={42719:function($0,$1,$2){MONO.mono_wasm_add_typed_value("pointer",$0,{ptr_addr:$1,klass_addr:$2})},42819:function($0,$1,$2){MONO.mono_wasm_add_typed_value("array",$0,{objectId:$1,length:$2})},42926:function($0,$1,$2,$3,$4,$5){MONO.mono_wasm_add_typed_value($0,$1,{toString:$2,value_addr:$3,value_size:$4,klass:$5})},43048:function($0,$1,$2){MONO.mono_wasm_add_typed_value($0,$1,{toString:$2})},43388:function($0,$1,$2,$3,$4){MONO.mono_wasm_add_properties_var($0,{field_offset:$1,is_own:$2,attr:$3,owner_class:$4})},125764:function(){return STACK_MAX},125786:function(){return TOTAL_STACK},554847:function($0,$1){MONO.string_decoder.decode($0,$0+$1,true)},555220:function($0,$1,$2){var str=MONO.string_decoder.decode($0,$0+$1);try{var res=eval(str);if(res===null||res==undefined)return 0;res=res.toString();setValue($2,0,"i32")}catch(e){res=e.toString();setValue($2,1,"i32");if(res===null||res===undefined)res="unknown exception"}var buff=Module._malloc((res.length+1)*2);stringToUTF16(res,buff,(res.length+1)*2);return buff},555639:function($0,$1,$2,$3){var message=Module.UTF8ToString($3)+": "+Module.UTF8ToString($1);if($2)console.trace(message);switch(Module.UTF8ToString($0)){case"critical":case"error":console.error(message);break;case"warning":console.warn(message);break;case"message":console.log(message);break;case"info":console.info(message);break;case"debug":console.debug(message);break;default:console.log(message);break}}};function compile_function(snippet_ptr,len,is_exception){try{var data=MONO.string_decoder.decode(snippet_ptr,snippet_ptr+len);var wrapper="(function () { "+data+" })";var funcFactory=eval(wrapper);var func=funcFactory();if(typeof func!=="function"){throw new Error("Code must return an instance of a JavaScript function. "+"Please use `return` statement to return a function.")}setValue(is_exception,0,"i32");return BINDING.js_to_mono_obj(func)}catch(e){res=e.toString();setValue(is_exception,1,"i32");if(res===null||res===undefined)res="unknown exception";return BINDING.js_to_mono_obj(res)}}__ATINIT__.push({func:function(){___wasm_call_ctors()}});function demangle(func){return func}function demangleAll(text){var regex=/\b_Z[\w\d_]+/g;return text.replace(regex,function(x){var y=demangle(x);return x===y?x:y+" ["+x+"]"})}function jsStackTrace(){var err=new Error;if(!err.stack){try{throw new Error}catch(e){err=e}if(!err.stack){return"(no stack trace available)"}}return err.stack.toString()}function stackTrace(){var js=jsStackTrace();if(Module["extraStackTrace"])js+="\n"+Module["extraStackTrace"]();return demangleAll(js)}function ___assert_fail(condition,filename,line,func){abort("Assertion failed: "+UTF8ToString(condition)+", at: "+[filename?UTF8ToString(filename):"unknown filename",line,func?UTF8ToString(func):"unknown function"])}var _emscripten_get_now;if(ENVIRONMENT_IS_NODE){_emscripten_get_now=function(){var t=process["hrtime"]();return t[0]*1e3+t[1]/1e6}}else if(typeof dateNow!=="undefined"){_emscripten_get_now=dateNow}else _emscripten_get_now=function(){return performance.now()};var _emscripten_get_now_is_monotonic=true;function setErrNo(value){HEAP32[___errno_location()>>2]=value;return value}function _clock_gettime(clk_id,tp){var now;if(clk_id===0){now=Date.now()}else if((clk_id===1||clk_id===4)&&_emscripten_get_now_is_monotonic){now=_emscripten_get_now()}else{setErrNo(28);return-1}HEAP32[tp>>2]=now/1e3|0;HEAP32[tp+4>>2]=now%1e3*1e3*1e3|0;return 0}function ___clock_gettime(a0,a1){return _clock_gettime(a0,a1)}var ExceptionInfoAttrs={DESTRUCTOR_OFFSET:0,REFCOUNT_OFFSET:4,TYPE_OFFSET:8,CAUGHT_OFFSET:12,RETHROWN_OFFSET:13,SIZE:16};function ___cxa_allocate_exception(size){return _malloc(size+ExceptionInfoAttrs.SIZE)+ExceptionInfoAttrs.SIZE}function ExceptionInfo(excPtr){this.excPtr=excPtr;this.ptr=excPtr-ExceptionInfoAttrs.SIZE;this.set_type=function(type){HEAP32[this.ptr+ExceptionInfoAttrs.TYPE_OFFSET>>2]=type};this.get_type=function(){return HEAP32[this.ptr+ExceptionInfoAttrs.TYPE_OFFSET>>2]};this.set_destructor=function(destructor){HEAP32[this.ptr+ExceptionInfoAttrs.DESTRUCTOR_OFFSET>>2]=destructor};this.get_destructor=function(){return HEAP32[this.ptr+ExceptionInfoAttrs.DESTRUCTOR_OFFSET>>2]};this.set_refcount=function(refcount){HEAP32[this.ptr+ExceptionInfoAttrs.REFCOUNT_OFFSET>>2]=refcount};this.set_caught=function(caught){caught=caught?1:0;HEAP8[this.ptr+ExceptionInfoAttrs.CAUGHT_OFFSET>>0]=caught};this.get_caught=function(){return HEAP8[this.ptr+ExceptionInfoAttrs.CAUGHT_OFFSET>>0]!=0};this.set_rethrown=function(rethrown){rethrown=rethrown?1:0;HEAP8[this.ptr+ExceptionInfoAttrs.RETHROWN_OFFSET>>0]=rethrown};this.get_rethrown=function(){return HEAP8[this.ptr+ExceptionInfoAttrs.RETHROWN_OFFSET>>0]!=0};this.init=function(type,destructor){this.set_type(type);this.set_destructor(destructor);this.set_refcount(0);this.set_caught(false);this.set_rethrown(false)};this.add_ref=function(){var value=HEAP32[this.ptr+ExceptionInfoAttrs.REFCOUNT_OFFSET>>2];HEAP32[this.ptr+ExceptionInfoAttrs.REFCOUNT_OFFSET>>2]=value+1};this.release_ref=function(){var prev=HEAP32[this.ptr+ExceptionInfoAttrs.REFCOUNT_OFFSET>>2];HEAP32[this.ptr+ExceptionInfoAttrs.REFCOUNT_OFFSET>>2]=prev-1;return prev===1}}function CatchInfo(ptr){this.free=function(){_free(this.ptr);this.ptr=0};this.set_base_ptr=function(basePtr){HEAP32[this.ptr>>2]=basePtr};this.get_base_ptr=function(){return HEAP32[this.ptr>>2]};this.set_adjusted_ptr=function(adjustedPtr){var ptrSize=4;HEAP32[this.ptr+ptrSize>>2]=adjustedPtr};this.get_adjusted_ptr=function(){var ptrSize=4;return HEAP32[this.ptr+ptrSize>>2]};this.get_exception_ptr=function(){var isPointer=___cxa_is_pointer_type(this.get_exception_info().get_type());if(isPointer){return HEAP32[this.get_base_ptr()>>2]}var adjusted=this.get_adjusted_ptr();if(adjusted!==0)return adjusted;return this.get_base_ptr()};this.get_exception_info=function(){return new ExceptionInfo(this.get_base_ptr())};if(ptr===undefined){this.ptr=_malloc(8);this.set_adjusted_ptr(0)}else{this.ptr=ptr}}var exceptionCaught=[];function exception_addRef(info){info.add_ref()}function ___cxa_begin_catch(ptr){var catchInfo=new CatchInfo(ptr);var info=catchInfo.get_exception_info();if(!info.get_caught()){info.set_caught(true);__ZSt18uncaught_exceptionv.uncaught_exceptions--}info.set_rethrown(false);exceptionCaught.push(catchInfo);exception_addRef(info);return catchInfo.get_exception_ptr()}var exceptionLast=0;function ___cxa_free_exception(ptr){return _free(new ExceptionInfo(ptr).ptr)}function exception_decRef(info){if(info.release_ref()&&!info.get_rethrown()){var destructor=info.get_destructor();if(destructor){Module["dynCall_ii"](destructor,info.excPtr)}___cxa_free_exception(info.excPtr)}}function ___cxa_end_catch(){_setThrew(0);var catchInfo=exceptionCaught.pop();exception_decRef(catchInfo.get_exception_info());catchInfo.free();exceptionLast=0}function ___resumeException(catchInfoPtr){var catchInfo=new CatchInfo(catchInfoPtr);var ptr=catchInfo.get_base_ptr();if(!exceptionLast){exceptionLast=ptr}catchInfo.free();throw ptr}function ___cxa_find_matching_catch_3(){var thrown=exceptionLast;if(!thrown){return(setTempRet0(0),0)|0}var info=new ExceptionInfo(thrown);var thrownType=info.get_type();var catchInfo=new CatchInfo;catchInfo.set_base_ptr(thrown);if(!thrownType){return(setTempRet0(0),catchInfo.ptr)|0}var typeArray=Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);var thrownBuf=0;HEAP32[thrownBuf>>2]=thrown;for(var i=0;i<typeArray.length;i++){var caughtType=typeArray[i];if(caughtType===0||caughtType===thrownType){break}if(___cxa_can_catch(caughtType,thrownType,thrownBuf)){var adjusted=HEAP32[thrownBuf>>2];if(thrown!==adjusted){catchInfo.set_adjusted_ptr(adjusted)}return(setTempRet0(caughtType),catchInfo.ptr)|0}}return(setTempRet0(thrownType),catchInfo.ptr)|0}function ___cxa_throw(ptr,type,destructor){var info=new ExceptionInfo(ptr);info.init(type,destructor);exceptionLast=ptr;if(!("uncaught_exception"in __ZSt18uncaught_exceptionv)){__ZSt18uncaught_exceptionv.uncaught_exceptions=1}else{__ZSt18uncaught_exceptionv.uncaught_exceptions++}throw ptr}var PATH={splitPath:function(filename){var splitPathRe=/^(\/?|)([\s\S]*?)((?:\.{1,2}|[^\/]+?|)(\.[^.\/]*|))(?:[\/]*)$/;return splitPathRe.exec(filename).slice(1)},normalizeArray:function(parts,allowAboveRoot){var up=0;for(var i=parts.length-1;i>=0;i--){var last=parts[i];if(last==="."){parts.splice(i,1)}else if(last===".."){parts.splice(i,1);up++}else if(up){parts.splice(i,1);up--}}if(allowAboveRoot){for(;up;up--){parts.unshift("..")}}return parts},normalize:function(path){var isAbsolute=path.charAt(0)==="/",trailingSlash=path.substr(-1)==="/";path=PATH.normalizeArray(path.split("/").filter(function(p){return!!p}),!isAbsolute).join("/");if(!path&&!isAbsolute){path="."}if(path&&trailingSlash){path+="/"}return(isAbsolute?"/":"")+path},dirname:function(path){var result=PATH.splitPath(path),root=result[0],dir=result[1];if(!root&&!dir){return"."}if(dir){dir=dir.substr(0,dir.length-1)}return root+dir},basename:function(path){if(path==="/")return"/";path=PATH.normalize(path);path=path.replace(/\/$/,"");var lastSlash=path.lastIndexOf("/");if(lastSlash===-1)return path;return path.substr(lastSlash+1)},extname:function(path){return PATH.splitPath(path)[3]},join:function(){var paths=Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,0);return PATH.normalize(paths.join("/"))},join2:function(l,r){return PATH.normalize(l+"/"+r)}};var PATH_FS={resolve:function(){var resolvedPath="",resolvedAbsolute=false;for(var i=arguments.length-1;i>=-1&&!resolvedAbsolute;i--){var path=i>=0?arguments[i]:FS.cwd();if(typeof path!=="string"){throw new TypeError("Arguments to path.resolve must be strings")}else if(!path){return""}resolvedPath=path+"/"+resolvedPath;resolvedAbsolute=path.charAt(0)==="/"}resolvedPath=PATH.normalizeArray(resolvedPath.split("/").filter(function(p){return!!p}),!resolvedAbsolute).join("/");return(resolvedAbsolute?"/":"")+resolvedPath||"."},relative:function(from,to){from=PATH_FS.resolve(from).substr(1);to=PATH_FS.resolve(to).substr(1);function trim(arr){var start=0;for(;start<arr.length;start++){if(arr[start]!=="")break}var end=arr.length-1;for(;end>=0;end--){if(arr[end]!=="")break}if(start>end)return[];return arr.slice(start,end-start+1)}var fromParts=trim(from.split("/"));var toParts=trim(to.split("/"));var length=Math.min(fromParts.length,toParts.length);var samePartsLength=length;for(var i=0;i<length;i++){if(fromParts[i]!==toParts[i]){samePartsLength=i;break}}var outputParts=[];for(var i=samePartsLength;i<fromParts.length;i++){outputParts.push("..")}outputParts=outputParts.concat(toParts.slice(samePartsLength));return outputParts.join("/")}};var TTY={ttys:[],init:function(){},shutdown:function(){},register:function(dev,ops){TTY.ttys[dev]={input:[],output:[],ops:ops};FS.registerDevice(dev,TTY.stream_ops)},stream_ops:{open:function(stream){var tty=TTY.ttys[stream.node.rdev];if(!tty){throw new FS.ErrnoError(43)}stream.tty=tty;stream.seekable=false},close:function(stream){stream.tty.ops.flush(stream.tty)},flush:function(stream){stream.tty.ops.flush(stream.tty)},read:function(stream,buffer,offset,length,pos){if(!stream.tty||!stream.tty.ops.get_char){throw new FS.ErrnoError(60)}var bytesRead=0;for(var i=0;i<length;i++){var result;try{result=stream.tty.ops.get_char(stream.tty)}catch(e){throw new FS.ErrnoError(29)}if(result===undefined&&bytesRead===0){throw new FS.ErrnoError(6)}if(result===null||result===undefined)break;bytesRead++;buffer[offset+i]=result}if(bytesRead){stream.node.timestamp=Date.now()}return bytesRead},write:function(stream,buffer,offset,length,pos){if(!stream.tty||!stream.tty.ops.put_char){throw new FS.ErrnoError(60)}try{for(var i=0;i<length;i++){stream.tty.ops.put_char(stream.tty,buffer[offset+i])}}catch(e){throw new FS.ErrnoError(29)}if(length)

// SIG // Begin signature block
// SIG // MIIntAYJKoZIhvcNAQcCoIInpTCCJ6ECAQExDzANBglg
// SIG // hkgBZQMEAgEFADB3BgorBgEEAYI3AgEEoGkwZzAyBgor
// SIG // BgEEAYI3AgEeMCQCAQEEEBDgyQbOONQRoqMAEEvTUJAC
```

This is a screenshot for illustration:

[image: SS showing Exception]

Comment: Web Assembly is shortened to **WASM** - not "WASAM" ...